# How can we implement observer pattern in .NET?

Tags: .net, design-patterns

In .NET architecture,there are lot of design patterns.I want to know about what is meant with observer pattern and how it is implemented

Answer (score 6):

The Observer pattern is pretty much reified in C# as events.

Comment: This is the only correct answer. The Observer is implemented by C# language.

Comment: @Vasiliy....He asked what is Observer pattern. Telling the OP that events in C# are observer patterns doesn't explain what Observers are.

Answer (score 5):

Wikipedia summarises it best:

> The observer pattern (a subset of the
>   publish/subscribe pattern) is a
>   software design pattern in which an
>   object, called the subject, maintains
>   a list of its dependents, called
>   observers, and notifies them
>   automatically of any state changes,
>   usually by calling one of their
>   methods. It is mainly used to
>   implement distributed event handling
>   systems.

An Observer (sometimes known as `publish-subscribe` pattern) is best used on GUI interfaces to update states of change on GUI objects such as all other objects can update itself (e.g. resizing a window, then all gui objects such as buttons can re-align itself based on window's size). This is usually done by introducing `EventListeners` (which is an Observer pattern).

For implementation, you can view the tutorial from either:

- MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998543.aspx
- Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

A good example of observer pattern is shown on MSDN.

You can find it here :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998543.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Check out [DOFactory](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternObserver.aspx).

They have :

- UML diagrams Advantages Disadvantages
- Summary of main items involved C#
- implementation  C# implementation for
- sample problem.

Answer (score 1):

this is a simple implementation of the observer pattern in c#, i added a lot of comments so hopefully it will be clear to you what it actually is :)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace SimpleObserver
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Newspaper newspaper = new Newspaper(); //create a Newspaper, which is a realization of Subject
            Grandma grandma = new Grandma(newspaper); //create a new Grandma, which is a realization of Observer
            newspaper.ChangeNews("no news today..."); //when the news get changed, grandma will automatically get it
            newspaper.ChangeNews("still no news..."); //and again
        }
    }

    //the subject which the observers are 'observing'
    //whenever something changes in the subject, the 
    //observers that are registered should be updated
    public interface Subject 
    {
        void RegisterObserver(Observer o); 
        void RemoveObserver(Observer o);
        void NotifyObservers(); 
    }

    //the actual subject, a newspaper which implements
    //the methods declared in the interface and it's own method
    //the goal is that whenever the news property changes 'by 
    //calling ChangeNews(string newNews); all the registered observers will
    //get that new news
    public class Newspaper : Subject
    {
        private List<Observer> observers = new List<Observer>(); //list with observers
        private string news = "initial news, nothing new!"; //the news

        public void RegisterObserver(Observer o)
        {
            this.observers.Add(o);
        }

        public void RemoveObserver(Observer o)
        {
            this.observers.Remove(o);
        }

        public void NotifyObservers()
        {
            foreach (Observer o in this.observers)
                o.Update(news); //update all the observers with the news
        }

        public void ChangeNews(string newNews) //method to manually change the news
        {
            this.news = newNews;
            this.NotifyObservers(); //automatically calls the NotifyObservers() method
        }
    }

    //the actual observer, has a method Update that will be
    //called by the Subject when something changes
    public interface Observer
    {
        void Update(string news);
    }

    //grandma is a observer, whenever the news changes she will be 
    //notified. she also has a reference to the subject instance, so
    //that she can cancel her subscription whenever needed
    public class Grandma : Observer
    {
        private Subject subject;

        public Grandma(Subject subject)
        {
            this.subject = subject; //set reference to the subject
            this.subject.RegisterObserver(this); //register to the subject
        }

        public void Update(string news)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Granny reads the news, very slowly...");
            Console.WriteLine("The news today is... " + news);
        }
    }

    //possibly other observers go here...
}
```